# 4-dimensions data became 2 dimensions after going throught convolutional neuron network

Tags: python, keras

I am training a neuron network with two types of input: image and BR (blue over red, it's kind of a non-image feature like height, weight...). To do that, i use fit function in keras, and convert image to list for input. But I don't know why the image list, which have 4 dimensions shape became 2 dimemsions when going into fit, and I got the error as below:

> Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have 3
>   dimensions, but got array with shape (1630, 1)

When I converted the image list to array, I had checked the shape of image_array and it has exactly 4 dimensions (particularly its shape is 1630, 60, 60, 3). Even right before the fit function, it still has the same shape. So I really don't know why the shape became (1630,1). Could anyone explain for me?

Here is my code:

```
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import os
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.layers import Input, Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense,Concatenate, concatenate,Reshape, BatchNormalization, Merge
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras import optimizers
from keras.optimizers import Adagrad
from sklearn import preprocessing
from scipy.misc import imread
import time
from PIL import Image 
import cv2
img_width, img_height = 60, 60
img_list = []
BR_list = []
label_list = []
data_num = 1630

folder1 = "cut2/train/sugi/"

folder2 = "cut2/train/hinoki/"

def imgConvert(file_path):
    img = imread(file_path,flatten = True)
    img = np.arange(1*3*60*60).reshape((60,60,3))
    img = np.array(img).reshape(60,60,3)
    img = img.astype("float32")
    return img

def B_and_R(img_path):
    img = cv2.imread(img_path)
    B = 0
    R = 0

    for i in range(25,35):
    #print(i)
        for j in range(25,35):
            B = B+img[i,j,0]
            R = R+img[i,j,2]
        #(j)
        #(img[i,j])

    ave_B = B/100
    ave_R = R/100

    BR = ave_B/ave_R
    return BR

def getData(path,pollen):
    for the_file in os.listdir(path):
        #print(the_file)
        file_path = os.path.join(path, the_file)
        B_over_R = B_and_R(file_path)
        img_arr = imgConvert(file_path)
        #writer.writerow([img_arr,B_over_R,"sugi"])
        img_list.append(img_arr)
        BR_list.append(B_over_R)
        lb = np.zeros(2)
        if pollen == "sugi":
            lb[0] +=1
        else:
            lb[1] +=1
        label_list.append(lb)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    getData(folder1,"sugi")
    getData(folder2,"hinoki")

    img_arr = np.array(img_list)
    print(img_arr.shape)
    #.reshape(img_list[0],1,img_width,img_height)
    img_arr.astype("float32")
    img_arr /= 255
    print(img_arr.shape)
    img_array = np.expand_dims(img_arr, axis = 0)
    img_array = img_array[0,:,:,:,:]
    print(img_array.shape)

    """
    datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        featurewise_center=True,
        featurewise_std_normalization=True,
        rotation_range=20,
        width_shift_range=0.2,
        height_shift_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)
    datagen.fit(img_array)
    """
    #img_array = img_array.reshape(img_array[0],1,img_width,img_height)

    print(img_array.shape)
    label_arr = np.array(label_list)
    print(label_arr.shape)
    #label_array = np.expand_dims(label_arr, axis = 0)
    #label_array = label_array[0,:,:,:,:]

    BR_arr = np.array(BR_list)
    print(BR_arr.shape)
    #BR_array = np.expand_dims(BR_arr, axis = 0)
    #BR_array = BR_array[0,:,:,:,:]

    #print(len([img_arr,BR_arr]))

    input_tensor = Input(shape=(img_width, img_height,3))
    vgg16 = VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_tensor=input_tensor)

    # FC層の作成
    top_model = Sequential()
    top_model.add(Flatten(input_shape=vgg16.output_shape[1:]))

#print(top_model.summary())

    # VGG16とFC層を結合してモデルを作成
    branch1 = Model(input=vgg16.input, output=top_model(vgg16.output))
#model.summary()
    print(branch1.summary())


    branch2 = Sequential()
    branch2.add(Dense(1, input_shape=(data_num,1), activation='sigmoid'))
    #branch1.add(Reshape(BR.shape, input_shape = BR.shape))
    branch2.add(BatchNormalization())
    branch2.add(Flatten())

    print(branch2.summary())
    merged = Merge([branch1, branch2], mode = "concat")

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(merged)
    model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

   #last_model = Model(input = [branch1.input,branch2.input],output=model())
    print(model.summary())
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=optimizers.SGD(lr=1e-3, momentum=0.9),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
    print(img_array.shape)
    model.fit([img_array,BR_arr], label_arr,
            epochs=5, batch_size=100, verbose=1)
```

Comment: The problem is in `branch2`. (That is the model that is expecting 3D, the other branch expects 4D.). Is `BR_arr` supposed to be one number per image? Or a single group of 1630 numbers repeated for all images?

Comment: Hi, it's a number per image. Particularly it's the ratio between blue and red pixel. I also findout that's the problem but not sure how to correct it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, then the problem is the input shape.

While your data for branch 2 is 2D `(batch, 1)`, your model should also have a 2D input: `input_shape = (1,)`. (Batch sizes are ignored in `input_shape`)